# .net MVC Routing to controller with optional parameters

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, routes, asp.net-mvc-routing

i have a quetion about MVC routing.

I have a controller method that is called with many different combinations of URL's. To overcome issue i am using optional parameters.

here is my controller method signature...

```
public ActionResult localMembersSearch(string Gender, string calling, [Optional]string Region, [Optional]string County, [Optional]string Town, [Optional]string queryvalues)
```

the first two parameters are not optional but always expected.

here is my URL route..

```
        routes.MapRoute(
            "memberDataSort",
            "MemberSearch/UKMembers/{Gender}/{Calling}/options/{*queryvalues}",
            new { controller = "MemberSearch", action = "localMembersSearch", Gender = "", Calling = "", Region = "", County = "", Town = "", queryvalues = "" }
        );
```

now what i would like is to be able to say that the string where {*queryvalues} is placed is set to the parameter 'queryvalues'.

as whats happening at the moment is the controller is getting called with "Gender", "Calling" and "Region".

is there a way in the Route i can explicity say, fill the 'queryvalues' parameter with {*queryvalues} ?

so the controller would recieve the signature below...

localMembersSearch("Gender", "Calling", "", "", "", "queryvalues")

any help is most apreciated ;)

Truegilly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just though about this and realized this obvious solution...

```
localMembersSearch("Gender", "Calling", "null", "null", "null", "queryvalues")
```

my controller method checks for relevant region, county, town data and so this works ok

truegilly